# Database of Cell Volumes by Cell Ontology?

Tags: database, single-cell

**Are there any databases that have aggregated information on cell volumes?**  Most useful would be a database keyed by cell ontology (e.g., `CL:0000236` for B cell).

The [BioNumbers book has a small table](http://book.bionumbers.org/how-big-is-a-human-cell/), but none of the references appear to link back to systematic catalogues.  In fact, just to put that small table together, they had to reference a dozen or so papers.

[The SHOGoiN database](http://shogoin.stemcellinformatics.org/) is a nice overview of the taxonomy, but the only morphological data available is attached to the images ([example B cell](http://shogoin.stemcellinformatics.org/image/cell/40)), which only includes areas and other histological measurements. Also, they don't seem to provide an API for programmatic access.

Comment: I disagree with the "opinion-based" close vote. The question is soliciting users to share any databases that have this information - not to rank them. The examples I gave are in the SO style of sharing what I already tried, neither of which are adequate solutions.

Comment: This is a useful question. I searched, and could find nothing matching this.